# Is Changing IF EXIST(SELECT 1 FROM ) to IF EXIST(SELECT TOP 1 FROM ) has any side effects?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have an existing SP running on my production server. I have found some significant performance gain from **changing** `IF EXIST(SELECT 1 FROM )` to `IF EXIST(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM )` and `IF NOT EXIST(SELECT 1 FROM )` to `IF NOT EXIST(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM )`. The only difference is **TOP** 1 keyword. Just curious to know whether changing this has any side effect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there should be no difference. `EXISTS` bails out as soon as it has found a single matching row. That's why it's always preferred over e.g. `(select COUNT(*) from ...) > 0` - a `COUNT` would force all rows to be considered.

If you create the following four queries:

```
select * from sys.objects
select top 1 * from sys.objects
select 1 where exists(select * from sys.objects)
select 1 where exists(select top 1 * from sys.objects)
```

And turn on execution plans, you'll see that the second query generates an execution plan that includes a `TOP` operator. The 3rd and 4th queries produce *identical* plans. The `TOP` is ignored.

Comment: Thanks. But I have found a significant performance gain by just adding TOP(1) on SQL SERVER 2012. From more than 20 seconds to 1 seconds.

Comment: Are you sure you did a fair test? The most common mistake people make is to just run one query after the other, forgetting that SQL Server will probably still have the table(s) cached in memory after the first query has run, and so the second query benefits from that.

Comment: I am 100% sure. Actually, I have background services that run after every 15 minutes. Before the same SP taken more than 20 seconds. Now just adding TOP(1) improved the performance. Note I have, IF EXISTS instead of where exists. But Thanks any way, I got the answer.

Answer (score -1):

When you add TOP 1, it does not continue to other rows. This is what makes the difference. Otherwise it will read whole table from start to end.

To check if a record exist or not, you don't need it as you are obviously going to add a where clause. There may be a tiny difference for that. You can get real performance difference by using indexes.

Using TOP matters only with order by.

Comment: Thanks. But I just need to check whether a row exist and/or not exist.